# Find submatrix with sum as close to k as possible

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matrix, data-structures

Is there an efficient algorithm to find a submatrix with a sum that is as close as possible to k (*must be rectangle*)? Matrix consists only of nonnegative integers. Faster than O(n^4), which involves iterating through all possible submatrices. Computing the sum can be done in O(1) time using prefix sums. I've thought about a similar problem in a 1D array, but couldn't figure out how to adapt it to matrices.

**Example:**

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]

k = 25
```

The answer is:
`[7, 8, 9]` with sum of 24

Comment: Can we assume all nonnegative entries? Then `O(n^3)` is doable.

Comment: @btilly yes, only nonnegative

Comment: @btilly any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

If the rectangle from `(i0, j0)` to `(i1, j1)` is too big, try the rectangle from `(i0, j0)` to `(i1-1, j1)` next. Otherwise try `(i1, j1+1)` next.

For each of `n^2` upper left corners you will try `O(n)` bottom right corners for `O(n^3)`.

Comment: tysm, solved!!!